# How to use below condition in a proper way

Tags: apex, community, workflow

Hi friends i got a requirement to get the mail id of the person to sent an email alert.But i have two conditions to work on this

Like

```
 OR(IF( CONTAINS( Mail__c , "pavanobbeli@gmail.com") ,
     "", "pavanobbeli89@gmail.com"),
      IF( CONTAINS( Mail__c ,
      "pavanobbeli89@gmail.com") ,"", "pavanobbeli@gmail.com"))
```

But it throws an error like expected Boolean received text.When i had work with single value it works fine.

Please provide suggestions where i had went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`OR` expects an array of `Boolean` parameters, then returns `true` if any of them are `true`, else it returns `false`. In your case, you are yielding `String` from your `IF` statements, and passing them into an `OR` function. The following would work, though it's unclear if it's what you're after:

```
OR(
    CONTAINS(Mail__c, "address1"),
    CONTAINS(Mail__c, "address2")
)
```

You should use the above as your criteria, then use a `Field Update` to actually set the value.

Comment: But i want to validate email in Mail_c and then update the value @Adrian Larson

Comment: If you want to update the value, you should be using `Workflow Rule`, not a `Validation Rule`.

Comment: Ya i am using the above condition in a workflow rule.But when i try to use like with out OR and only single condition it 's updating correctly @Adrian Larson

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use CASE:

```
CASE(Mail__c, 
CONTAINS(Mail__c,"pavanobbeli@gmail.com"),"pavanobbeli89@gmail.com",
CONTAINS( Mail__c ,"pavanobbeli89@gmail.com"),"pavanobbeli@gmail.com")
```

**EDIT**

According to the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US), you can't use functions in your formula that return true or false which is what CONTAINS does. Instead, it needs to return a non-boolean value. Since these seem to be complete addresses, try the following and see if it works for you :

```
CASE(Mail__c, 
"pavanobbeli@gmail.com","pavanobbeli89@gmail.com",
"pavanobbeli89@gmail.com","pavanobbeli@gmail.com")
```

Comment: Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'CASE()'. Expected 4, received 5 @crmprogdev

Comment: Remove the Mail__c at the very start of the statement and see if that works, but I'd expect you to need it. Actually, you probably need to add the object name in front of Mail__c.

Comment: And now agian Error: Incorrect argument type for function 'CASE()'. @crmprogdev

Comment: See my edited answer and see if works for you.

Comment: I found another solution it's working fine.I will give a try to solution also.@crmprogdev

Answer (score -1):

Hey i found the solution the solution to use IF with Contains functions.Here the solution

```
 IF(CONTAINS( Approver_Mail__c,"pavanobbeli@gmail.com"),"pavanobbeli89@gmail.com",
 IF(CONTAINS( Approver_Mail__c , "pavanobbeli89@gmail.com"), "pavanobbeli@gmail.com",NULL ))
```

It works perfectly fine thank you very much every one.

Comment: The root cause is that you were trying to put your field update in your criteria, no?

Comment: No.I am trying this in an standard approval process with a field update.Whenever a record is approved in a specific criteria like if reassigned. It's working fine.@Adrian Larson